# Cloud saved data missing

Tags: terraria-mobile

I recently redownloaded this game, and I had almost everything unlocked, but when I came back to the newly updated version, all of my progress was missing, including my cloud saved data. Can somebody please help me find out how to get my stuff back?

Comment: What kind of phone do you have? Also, did you ever actually upload your character to the cloud

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you own an Android*

Basically, all you need to do is:

- Sign into the email account you used to save the cloud saves, go into your Google Drive (with that email), and look for a folder named *Terraria*.
- Go into that folder and grab the files that end in **.world** (if you want your character, the file would end in **.player**).
- Go to your file explorer (if your phone didn't come with one, download one from google play store) and go to *android/data/com.and.games505.Terraria/OldSaves/Worlds* and place your *world* file. (*android/data/com.and.games505.Terraria/OldSaves/player* for your *.player* file.)

Now the world (and player) should show up in the game.

Comment: Capitalization and punctuation would help, too.

Comment: I changed it a little. If you don't like it, you can revert the changes.

Comment: Well @jacob sites, I play on a Old Gen Console, and for all I know, you sadly can't recover you're progress if you uninstalled you Terraria app.

Comment: @Lsootgamer13 jacob is referring to the 1.2 update via google cloud saves, so as long as he didnt delete the terraria folder in his google drive, he is still able to get his files back

Comment: That would make sense now.

Comment: @Lsootgamer13 yeah lol

Comment: It would be a different story for Old Gen Consoles.

Comment: the old gen Consoles did not have google cloud save.